# Importing an exported Mac-generated R dataset into SAS on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, macos, r, sas

I have a .csv file generated by R on a Mac. I'd like to import the dataset into SAS in Windows XP. Note that there are many missing values in my .csv file (NA's). How could I import the dataset into SAS without them? I'd like SAS to change all NA's automatically to ".", but it is often difficult even to get Mac-generated .csv files into SAS 9.3 at all.

I tried "write.dbf()" from the foreign library and I generated a .dbf file but unfortunately, SAS DBMS does not know .dbf.

Comment: I don't know R at all, but one of your comments mentioned problems using a MAC generated CSV file on your Windows machine. That is because a CSV file is just a plain text file and plain text files are encoded differently between UNIX, MAC, and Windows. To have SAS read a text file that was created on a MAC, add the option `TERMSTR=CR` to your INFILE statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the R `write.table` function, there is an argument `na="NA"`  Change this to `na="."`

You could also just use find and replace in excel.

Comment: Hi @chandler, I tried many different ways before including na = ".", but seems that there is an issue on loading a mac generated .csv file from windows. My SAS is on windows XP. Usually, with SAS 9.3. almost always, I cannot read my MAC .csv files. It's funny that with other SAS versions, it's not the case !

Comment: This must had to do with the way the file is being encoded. I've never had to play around this, but there is an argument `fileEncoding`. This might solve your issue. What happens if you run the R program on windows?

Comment: Chandler, it seems that something is wrong with SAS 9.3. I tried SAS 9.1 and I was able to import the data! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how to do that as you're reading in the data, but you should be able to use a normal infile statement, then an if/then. Something like:

```
DATA new;
infile 'C:\myfolder\mydataset.csv' dlm=',' firstobs=2;
if newvar1='NA' then newvar1=.;
```

If you give me more details about your dataset, I may be able to help you more.

I also wonder if you could get the same effect by replacing the NAs with ' ' or numeric(0) in R before exporting it to send to SAS? IMO R is more flexible, so I prefer to do my data manipulation there.

Comment: Hi Liz, thank you for your comment. As I wrote for chandler above, it seems that there is an issue on loading a mac generated .csv file from windows. My SAS is on windows XP. Usually, with SAS 9.3. almost always, I cannot read my MAC .csv files. It's funny that with other SAS versions, it's not the case !

Comment: Hi Sepehr, sorry to hear that you're still having issues. Unfortunately I don't have access to a Mac, so it's hard for me to give you much guidance. I'll add an edit to your question, and hopefully people with more experience with Mac-Windows issues will take a look!

Comment: Hi Liz, seems that there is a bug in SAS 9.3. I used SAS 9.1 and I was able to import the data! Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `R` to write an SAS XPORT formatted file. See `write.xport` in the [`SASxport` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SASxport/).

Comment: Thank you Brian for your comment.